# Count Distinct of a dimension in druid

Tags: druid

I am trying to get distinct of the count of a dimension territory. But I think what I am getting is distinct of the count of (date, territory).
Here is the query:

```
{
   "queryType": "groupBy",
   "dataSource": "model",
   "granularity": "all",
   "filter": {
   "type": "selector", "dimension": "District", "value": "ATLANTA"},


   "aggregations":[  
      {"name":"!t5", "type":"distinctCount","fieldName":"Territory"},
      {"name":"!T_4","type":"longSum","fieldName":"Units"}
   ],
   "postAggregations":[  
      {  
         "type":"arithmetic",
         "fn":"*",
         "fields":[  
            {  
               "type":"arithmetic",
               "fn":"/",
               "fields":[  
                  {  
                     "type":"fieldAccess",
                     "fieldName":"!T_4"
                  },
                  {  
                     "type":"fieldAccess",
                     "fieldName":"!t5"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "type":"constant",
               "value":1
            }
         ],
         "name":"AverageDistrict"
      }
   ],
   "intervals": ["2018-06-13T00:00Z/2018-07-25T00:00Z"]
}
```

so when I am changing the date range, the count of distinct(!t5) also increases. Whereas in the raw data the count of distinct is always constant throughout all the date ranges.
What I need is the count of distinct values of territory for that date range. I hope I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use 'cardinality' aggregator in place of 'distinctCount' aggregator. Hope this helps.